# How delete relation belongs_to - has_one between objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two models: `Project` with `has_one :performer` and `Performer` with `belongs_to :project`

I have object project with relationship with performer like `project.performer`

How can I delete this relationship? I need the attribute `performer_id` to have value `nil`.

Comment: How is it possible that your foreign key is nil. ? What are the issues you are facing in managing relations . Why you want to remove relation ? Give more details may help solving your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just update your `Project` object.

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  def remove_performer
    update(performer_id: nil)
  end
  ...
end
```

Add method `remove_performer` , then you can use it to remove performer from project.

```
proj = Project.new
proj.remove_performer
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correct you can simply remove `has_one` and `belongs_to` from your models.

**UPDATE**
To set `performer_id` to `nil` for particular object you can do

```
project.update_column :project, nil
```

This will skip any validations. Of course your database schema should allow `NULL` value for `projects.performer_id`.

**Note:** In Rails 4 `update_column` is equal to `update_columns`.
Read more in [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update_columns).

Comment: no, i need only delete this relationship for current object